# Проблема с z-lib

Tags: c++, zlib

Допустим я использую Bullet Physics у которого лицензия Z-Lib, в пунктах этой лицензии упоминается что я не имею право присваивать этот продукт себе, и у этого физического движка весьма странный CC который мне не подходит, могу ли я написать такой код:

`using Shape = btCollisionShape;`

... и не попасть в зал суда?

Comment: в России хоть что можешь написать и не попасть в зал суда

Comment: Это весьма радует ;)

Comment: [tl;dr;](https://tldrlegal.com/license/zlib-libpng-license-(zlib))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можете! Иначе это был бы абсурд.

Вы не можете искажать сведения о том, кто автор библиотеки.

`using Shape = btCollisionShape;` этого никаким образом не делает.

Вот скажем, если вы будете всем рассказывать, что в вашей программе используется крутой *самодельный* физический движок - это будет нарушением.

---

Вот текст лицензии, на всякий случай:

```
Copyright (c) <''year''> <''copyright holders''>

This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
warranty. In no event will the authors be held liable for any damages
arising from the use of this software.

Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
freely, subject to the following restrictions:

1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
   claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this software
   in a product, an acknowledgment in the product documentation would be
   appreciated but is not required.
2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
   misrepresented as being the original software.
3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
```

Comment: Вот это хорошо, а то дико глаза режет эта приставка ;)